# Changing the path of a project

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

While changing the path of a project in my computer(cutting it and pasting somewhere else), the application that was running correctly before doesn't run anymore. The same is true about running an application written by another laptop as well.

I thought it had to do something with the various version of OpenCv in each laptop but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: after changing path restart android studio

Comment: Make sure your current path is not too long, some time Studio throws error in case your project path it too long.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.